# Clicking HMTL5 Canvas causes select all

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a canvas that uses shapes with hitregions to act like buttons, so I can do something when they are clicked. However sometimes when I click a button suddenly my whole screen is selected, similar to when you press Ctrl + a when viewing a webpage.

How does this happen, is there anyone else that has come across something similar or knows what property of the canvas might help prevent this?

I have looked around but could find nobody with a similar issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style `user-select: none` to your body tag to prevent the whole screen selection.

```
body {
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Solves the problem but seems a bit drastic for my case. Applying this to only the canvas item also solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: Ya, I knew it was a bit drastic, but I thought you don't have any other elements on your page except for the canvas. Anyways, glad that it solved your problem :)